# Analytical expression for the integral $I(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2-ax^4}dx$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am interested in calculating the integral
$$
I(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2-ax^4}dx,
$$

where $a>0$. After expanding $e^{-ax^4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-a)^n}{n!}x^{4n}$, we
find
$$
I(a)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-a)^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty x^{4n}e^{-x^2}dx.
$$
We can solve the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{4n}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{d^{2n}}{dk^{2n}}\left.\int_0^\infty e^{-kx^2}dx\right|_{k=1}=\left.\frac12\frac{d^{2n}}{dk^{2n}}\sqrt{\frac\pi k}\;\right|_{k=1}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\frac{(4n-1)!!}{2^{2n}}
$$
Hence, we find
$$
I(a)= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-a)^n}{n!}\frac{(4n-1)!!}{2^{2n}},
$$
where $(-1)!!=1$.
In the above, I assumed I can change the order between the summation and the integration. I think that is fine, since the expansion of $e^{-ax^4}$ converges uniformly.
I have some old notes in which I stated, based on a Mathematica integration, that
$$
I(a)=\frac1{4\sqrt{a}}e^{\frac1{8a}}K_{1/4}\left(\frac1{8a}\right),
$$
where $K_{1/4}$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.
This is a black box to me and I am not sure if it will make the numerical expansion easier to obtain.

1. Is my demonstration correct?
2. Is there a simpler alternative (closed) form?
3. How fast does this sum converge? Can I split the alternating summation into a positive and a negative part? I believe it converges absolutely.
4. Is the Mathematica expression equivalent to the summation I found?

a similar question has been asked before:
[mathexchange question 4011739](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4011739/calculating-the-integral-int-z-infty-e-ax4bx2dx)

Remark: I would like to add that a version of this integral is in Gradshteyn-Ryzhik, formula 3.323.3. I did not see a proof in the reference given there:
A. Erdelyi "Tables of Integral Transformations", vol. 1 page 147.
I found three "proofs" in Viktor Moll's Special Integrals
of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik: the Proofs - Volume II, pages 109-116.
All these demonstrations seem very complicated to me though.

Comment: Maple agrees with the Mathematica closed form.  Its expansion of that in a power series agrees with your series at least to 100 terms.  This suggests (but does not prove) that the answer to 4 is YES.

Comment: **Q2** The expression in terms of $K_{1/4}$ is likely the simplest you will get. Look at the [integral representations](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32), after some substitutions it looks like you can write $I(a)$ using eq. 10.32.8. 


**Q3** I do not think the sum converges. The terms are getting bigger! You have produced an asymptotic series by expanding about the singular point $a=0$ (notice that $I(a)$ diverges for $a<0$).

Comment: @minimax You may also be interested in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1013142/348034). However, there is a mistake in the last formula, as pointed out in comments. The last comment gives the correct expression.

Comment: For question 3 you can use the ratio test to prove the series doesn't converge. You can re-write your series as $\sum_{n\ge0} \frac{(-a)^n(4n)!}{2^{4n} n! (2n)!}$ using [properties of the double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Relation_to_the_factorial), and by taking the ratio $$\Big\lvert\frac{ a_{n+1}}{a_n} \Big\rvert = \rvert a \lvert \frac{(4n+3)(4n+1)}{4(n+1)}\to \infty> 1$$